# How to find and child array which items not intersect each other in array contain 200,000 items fastest

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array contain 200K rectangle object with x,y,w,h. I want to find an result array contain items that not intersect with each other. My way is loop each item and compare with N - 1 object in array, but it very slow and cost time with complexity is O(n^n). Are there any faster solution ? Thank you.

Comment: I think you are looking for clipping algorithm here.

Comment: As far as I understand...do you want in the end to have only one object which is not deleted/disabled/hidden? If so, how about sorting the objects in the array and just show the first or last one?

Comment: You might want to consider the fact that in order for rectangles to be in-front of or behind one-another, you need another measurement - height/depth. Without it, there can be no concept of behind or in front - you can only determine if they exist at the same 2d X,Y position. ;) Ooops!

Comment: @Mis94 What i want is an array which items not intersect each other, it will have less than 200k

Comment: I edited the question make guys confuse and difficult to understand

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely similar to `line segment intersection` problem. Have a look at [this](https://www.topcoder.com/community/competitive-programming/tutorials/line-sweep-algorithms/).

Bentley–Ottmann algorithm also does this with a good time complexity.

The performance could be improved to O(nlogn), by using range query searches. So the idea is to sort all your rectangles based on let's say 'Y-coordinates', feed the rectangles in a segment tree.

Now, for each rectangle if you want to know if a given side is overlapping any other rectangles, you could do a quick lookup with range query on the segment tree.

I have left the answer a bit vague to promote OP's thought and not giveaway everything.